# WCF listens to TCP port

Tags: wcf, tcpclient

I am using a TCP port with WCF service. I have hardware that sends ASCII messages throw TCP port.

I have already implemented WCF service, I need to add TCP endpoint to it to listen this port, getting ASCII message then makes some processing on it.
Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

WCF won't help you in this scenario as it supports only SOAP messages.
SOAP is a protocol specification for exchanging information in WCF/Web Services and relies on XML for its message format.

You can not use WCF as a traditionnal tcp server to parse ASCII messages. These messages have to be structured.

Comment: Thanks Cybermaxs for quick reply, great, but wcf message custom encoder can't perform that?

Comment: maybe ... but WCF by default uses SOAP. WCF team works on .net 3.5 to add non-Soap formatting with WCF REST(Json/Xml) for HTTP. I don't know your WCF skills but it seems to be a very complicated tech challenge and largely out of the box.

Comment: great, but how can I perform this, by which technique?
Thanks so much Cybermaxs